# Fetching CorrelationId header of the ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application and i am using AggregatingKafkaReplyingTemplate for utilizing request reply pattern with another downstream service.

Currently i am testing the same with a Spring boot producer application running locally and a Local Kafka Ui which sends the message back on the replying topic done manually after knowing that the request message has been sent on the producer topic.

Is there any way to log/know the generated string value (not the bytes) CorrelationId by Kafka template in the Spring boot app itself (in logs maybe ) ? Can i take that value and put it in the local Kafka UI to send a message back in the receiving topic ?

i tried getting the UUID generated from Kafka template through debugging in the template class and sending it through my local Kafka UI. But then the correlation validation fails and i get this message.

```
No pending reply: <CorrelationId> perhaps timed out, or using a shared reply topic
```

I checked the actual UUID is not logged but the hash key of the byte value and bytes itself of the UUID is logged.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Currently Spring Kafka logs CorrelationId in Binary format.

But we can write a Kafka Producer and Consumer interceptor to customize the header values.

Thanks to Gary Russell for the help and advice.

Please check here for the details and the interceptor code for modifying the headers.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2399

Going forward CorrelationId will be also logged in string as per the new enhancement accepted.